# How to match not null + not empty?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have to do some queries on a messy database. Some columns are filled with either `null` or an empty string. I can do a query like this:

```sql
select * from a where b is not null and b <> '';
```

But is there a shortcut for this case? (match every "not empty" value) Something like:

```sql
select * from a where b is filled;
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question is `null or empty` while this question is `not null and not empty`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just:

```
where b <> ''
```

will do what you want as `null <> ''` is null and the row will not be returned

Comment: or `LTRIM(b) <> ''` if there's the possibility of rows with more than a single space.

Comment: `invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`
so, if column b is INT then `b <> 0`   
but your answer is enough correct for the Q: '...or an empty string'

Answer (score 3):

`select * from a where COALESCE(b, '') <> '';`