# Filtering out blank spaces

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query a table and get all rows where the column i_vhcl_recal is not empty.
I ran the following below and kept getting rows that appeared to be empty.  Upon inspection, that the fields weren't null but instead they were a string of blank spaces.

How to I query rows where i_vhcl_recal has an actual value and not blank spaces or nulls?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE i_vhcl_recal IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938704/how-to-match-not-null-not-empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match not null + not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938704/how-to-match-not-null-not-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (i_vhcl_recal <> '') IS NOT TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a regex:

```
select * from table where i_vhcl_recal is not null and i_vhcl_recal !~ '^\s*$';
```

The interesting thing about `'\s'` is that it matches on a variety of space characters such as: carriage return, line feed, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed.